# Foreach into Parallel.Foreach c#

Tags: c#, lambda, parallel-processing

I have the following foreach loop and want to paralise it to improve the speed at which my application reads a list of .csv files. Any help in converting this into a lambda would be very much appreciated!

```
foreach (var storeData in storeCodesData)

  {
      string[] storeDataSplit = storeData.Split(',');
      if (storeDataSplit[0] != "")
      {
          Store store1 = new Store { StoreCode = storeDataSplit[0], StoreLocation = storeDataSplit[1] };
          stores.Add(store1);
          storename.Add( storeDataSplit[1]);
      }
      PopulateListViewItems(storeDataSplit[0]);
  }
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, please be more careful with tag use - the Visual Studio tag is for questions about the tool itself, not for general code issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what are you asking for but based on your question, here is how you can do that. Keep in mind that your logic inside must be "paralleled-ready".

```
Parallel.ForEach(storeCodesData, (storeData) => 
      {
      string[] storeDataSplit = storeData.Split(',');
      if (storeDataSplit[0] != "")
      {
          Store store1 = new Store { StoreCode = storeDataSplit[0], StoreLocation = storeDataSplit[1] };
          stores.Add(store1);
          storename.Add( storeDataSplit[1]);
      }
      PopulateListViewItems(storeDataSplit[0]);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed! (I was getting the lambda expression wrong)

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you run into any issue. Btw, if it solved your question then please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Done! I have run into a new issue. I now receive a 'Cross-thread Operation not valid' error for the following method:

    `private void PopulateListViewItems(string item)

        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
                   
        }`

I think I need to make the method threadsafe but Im not too sure how! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can use put this code outside of Parallel.ForEach? For eg: create a List, add your listBoxItem into that list. After the parallel loop is done. Assign that list to `listBox1.Items`